# Пунктуация в чеховском предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Помогите объяснить постановку запятых в начале предложения.

**Крестьянин, в соломенной шляпе, сопит, пыхтит, переворачивается на все бока и не знает, куда положить свои длинные ноги.**

Answer (score 1):

> Кто-то лезет в мой задний карман. В кармане нет ничего, но все-таки ужасно... Я оборачиваюсь. Предо мной незнакомец. На нем соломенная шляпа и темно-серая блуза.
>   <...>
>   В моем вагоне все то же: тьма, храп, табачный и сивушный запахи, пахнет русским духом. Возле меня храпит рыженький судебный следователь, едущий в Киев из Рязани... В двух-трех шагах от следователя дремлет хорошенькая... **Крестьянин, в соломенной шляпе, сопит, пыхтит, переворачивается на все бока и не знает, куда положить свои длинные ноги.** Кто-то в углу закусывает и чамкает во всеуслышание... Под скамьями спит богатырским сном народ.
>   [А. П. Чехов. В вагоне](http://ruslib.us/LITRA/CHEHOW/vagon.txt)

Я думаю, что выделенное запятыми выражение *в соломенной шляпе* является несогласованным определением — оно обособлено **с целью придания ему большей значимости** (в данном контексте потребовалось выделить особый признак).
Обособленные несогласованные определения синонимичны придаточным предложениям.

Вот классический пример.
*Шабашкин, с картузом на голове, стоял подбочась и гордо взирал около себя.*
Здесь косвенно подчеркивается наглость Шабашкина, мелкого чиновника, который не снял головного убора в присутствии дворянина.

В нашем же предложении Чехов пытается обратить внимание читателя на то, что это именно тот крестьянин, в соломенной шляпе, — он ранее уже упоминался (при попытке кражи).

[Обособление несогласованных определений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/715-234_obosoblenie_nesoglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)

Answer (score 1):

*Крестьянин, **в соломенной шляпе**, сопит, пыхтит, переворачивается на все бока и не знает, куда положить свои длинные ноги.*

Вообще говоря, если существительное имеет **неопределенное значение** (человек, крестьянин, гражданин и др.), то единственное несогласованное определение обычно **не обособляется**, так как указывает на **отличительный** признак лица.

Но в данном случае обособление связано с тем, что этот признак **упоминался раньше.** Поэтому здесь такой смысл: *крестьянин, **тот самый,** в соломенной шляпе.*

Answer (score 0):

Автор посчитал "в соломенной шляпе" уточняющим оборотом, вот и обособил.
Особых причин так считать нет, но хозяин барин. При желании можно.
От контекста ещё многое зависит.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно таким образом выделяются уточнения, но в Вашем случае *в соломенной шляпе* скорее просто характеристика крестьянина, которую не стоит обособлять:

> *Крестьянин в соломенной шляпе сопит, пыхтит, переворачивается на все бока и не знает, куда положить свои длинные ноги.*